# English explanations of Code First Fluent mappings please

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

One of the selling points (I know a minor one) of a fluent API is that chains of fluent calls can resemble natural language, and this all looks great at first glance, but as is the case with the Code First fluent mapping API, the calls are just too far removed from English, all documentation I've seen always describes a whole call chain in one description.

I am looking for material the covers e.g. a fluent call chain like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Status>().HasRequired(s => s.Login).WithMany();
```

"A Status requires a Login and this Login can have many Statuses."

If I'm even correct in how I'm reading that chain, but I'm sure the reader knows what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make it little bit more complex to fully describe what the mapping means. Suppose that you have these two entities:

```
public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual LoginInfo Login { get; set; }
}

public class LoginInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    // No navigation property to Status
}
```

Now you write your mapping statement:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Status>().HasRequired(s => s.Login).WithMany();
```

The translation of this statement should be something like (I believe native speaker can form better explanation):

*The entity `Status` has mapped required navigation property `Login` for accessing related `LoginInfo` entity instance where that instance can be related to many statuses but it doesn't expose mapped navigation property to access them.*

The original fluent description hides information about `LoginInfo` because this generic argument of `HasRequired` is automatically inferred.